# make distance between acronym and description

Tags: formatting, glossaries, acronyms

i have a problem with my glossaries format. Is it possible to make a distance (hspace) between the acronym or symbol and their description?
now, it is something like that:

**Bsp.** Beispiel

Another question: Why I can only define acronyms oder symbols for \begin{document}?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Latin Modern
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}                % SI-Einheiten


%% Abkürzungs- und Symbolverrzeichnis
\usepackage[
automake,
nonumberlist,       % keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,            % ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,                % Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
section]            % im Inhaltsverzeichnis auf section-Ebene erscheinen
{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{acronyms}{sym}{sbl}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}        % Abkürzungsverzeichnis anlegen
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{Symbolverzeichnis}             % Symbolverzeichnis anlegen
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}       % Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\makeglossaries                             % Glossar-Befehle einschalten
%% Einträge siehe Ende der Präambel %%


%% Abkürzungsverzeichnis-Einträge mit \newacronym

% Allgemeine Abkürzungen
\newacronym{Bsp}{Bsp.}{Beispiel}
\newacronym{bspw}{bspw.}{beispielsweise}
\newacronym{bzg}{bzg.}{bezüglich}
\newacronym{bzw}{bzw.}{beziehungsweise}

\newacronym{ca}{ca.}{circa}

\newacronym{dh}{d.h.}{das heißt}

\newacronym{etc}{etc.}{et cetera}
\newacronym{evtl}{evtl.}{eventuell}

\newacronym{max}{max.}{maximal}
\newacronym{min}{min.}{minimal}

\newacronym{oÄ}{o.Ä.}{oder Ähnliches}
\newacronym{og}{o.g.}{oben genannt}

\newacronym{s}{s.}{siehe}
\newacronym{S}{S.}{Seite}

\newacronym{ua}{u.a.}{unter anderem}
\newacronym{usw}{usw.}{und so weiter}
\newacronym{uvm}{uvm.}{und vieles mehr}

\newacronym{vgl}{vgl.}{vergleiche}

\newacronym{zT}{z.T.}{zum Teil}
\newacronym{zzt}{zzt.}{zurzeit}
\newacronym{zzgl}{zzgl.}{zuzüglich}

% Spezielle Abkürzungen
\newacronym{pvc}{PVC}{Polyvinylchlorid}
\newacronym{test}{Test}{Dies ist ein test um die länge auszuprobieren}


%% Symbolverzeichnis-Einträge mit \newglossaryentry

\newglossaryentry{ohm}{type=symbols, name={\ensuremath{\Omega}}, %
    sort=Ohm, symbol={\ensuremath{\Omega}}, %
    description={unit of electrical resistance}}

\newglossaryentry{varphi}{type=symbols,name={$\varphi$},description={Phasenverschiebungswinkel}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Dokument-Beginn %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
\newpage
\printglossary[type=symbols]
\newpage
Test \gls{Bsp} and \gls{varphi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document is much too long and can not be compiled due to the \input.

Comment: now i change it..

Comment: Still much too long, neither biblatex nor tikz nor some header definition is needed to demonstrate a problem with a glossary.

Comment: Sorry, but now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acronym list printed with a description list. You can adapt it e.g. with enumitem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Aktiviert EC-Schriftarten
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Dateikodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}         % Deutsche Einstellung

\usepackage[
automake,
nonumberlist,       % keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,            % ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,                % Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
section]            % im Inhaltsverzeichnis auf section-Ebene erscheinen
{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{acronyms}{sym}{sbl}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}        % Abkürzungsverzeichnis anlegen
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}       % Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\makeglossaries                             % Glossar-Befehle einschalten

\newacronym{Bsp}{Bsp.}{Beispiel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newglossarystyle{listspaced}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{description}[leftmargin=3cm,labelsep=!]}{\end{description}}}

\begin{document}

Test \gls{Bsp} 
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,style=listspaced]

\end{document}
```

[image]